# Puppeteer - fetching remote images without buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

We have NodeJS application with Puppeteer + Express.

Our goal is to fetch images data from remote url. Image bytes should be stream, because we dont need to load images into the memory.

Solution with buffer :

```
var express = require('express');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var app = express();

// express request/response
app.get('/', async function (req, res) {
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                        headless: true
                    });
let page = await browser.newPage();
let userAgent = getRandomUserAgent();
page.setUserAgent(userAgent);
page.setViewport({width:1024,height:768});  

const response = await page.goto(imageUrl, {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});

let data = await response.buffer();
res.send(data);
}
```

Question : how to fetch images as a stream to make for example like this :

```
{imageStreamFromPuppeeter}.pipe(res);
```

Comment: Why do you need puppeteer to get an image (a resource) from a URL?

Comment: @hardkoded our main fetcher is Puppeteer. We are fetching articles and we need to fetch images as well.It follow redirects and supports setting of user agent for example. U mean better to use simple "http" module? Or for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/request lib for fetching of resources as a stream?

Comment: Yeah, I think that if you only need to download a file you will perform way better removing puppeteer and downloading the file with any http library. Puppeteer won't "stream" data. It calls 'Network.getResponseBody' and chromium will return the whole base64 content.

Comment: @hardkoded thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you only need to download a file you will perform way better removing puppeteer and downloading the file with any http library. Puppeteer won't "stream" data. It calls 'Network.getResponseBody' and chromium will return the whole base64 content.